# Django templates {% if %}: what does it take to be equal?

Tags: python, django, templates

Here's a chunk of code from a Django template:

```
{% for customer in customers %}
    {% for div in divs|lookup:customer %}
        <p>:{{ div.custdiv_id }}: vs. :{{ currentDiv }}: ==>
            {% if div.custdiv_id == currentDiv %}
                YES!
            {% else %}
                NOPE.
            {% endif %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here's some of the output from that rendered template:

```
:1: vs. :1: ==> NOPE.
:7: vs. :1: ==> NOPE.
:5: vs. :1: ==> NOPE.
:9: vs. :1: ==> NOPE.
```

Why isn't :1: vs. :1: printing "YES"?  The colons are there to check if it isn't some spacing issue, which it doesn't appear to be; div.custdiv_id and currentDiv come from the same type on their respective models -- bigint(20).  I can't figure out what the issue is here.

Comment: The same *type* of value. Integer `1` and string `'1'` look the same in the template, but don't test equal.

Comment: You can try to add `|add:"0"` to coerce the values to integers.

Comment: Martijn, even though they both were pulled off a model object that has the relevant fields defined as the same type, I tested your theory, and you were right, one was coming across as Unicode and one a long.  Which means there's an even more mysterious bug afoot, but at least you solved my immediate problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do use `{% ifequal div.custdiv_id currentDiv %}`